# Retrieving HTML tags from sql server 2008 in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql

I am working on an adaptive quiz and I have stored in my database questions for this quiz. The quizzes and questions are about HTML which means that the quizzes cover the HTML lessons. The problem is that in my table questions in the database there are question title and 4 choices probably they are choices of HTML tags and the correct choice. While retrieving the choices of the correct answer for the question from the database in asp.net web form using c# and binding them to radio buttons, the HTML tags do not appear but they are executed in the web form for example:
 Question: What is the correct HTML tag for inserting a line break?

choice 1:
 choice 2:
 choice 3:
 choice 4:None of These

when I run the project nothing of this choices appear but "Non of These" and the "
 is executed which means that a line is passed.

In other questions which not contain choices of HTML tags it is ok all choices appear.

Comment: Sounds like you want `@Html.Raw(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind it directly you can do it explicitly with `foreach` loop e.g:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 choicesRadioButtonList.Items.Add(Server.HtmlEncode(row["choices"].ToString()));
}
```

Here the `dt` is the choices data which come from the `datasource table` and choices are within `choices` column.

`Server.HtmlEncode` doing it [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)